# Simplified HTML parsing for LEGO features

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The goal is to extract the  the `Features` section from a Lego product page. In the Features section, usually there's a header (`<h2>` or `<h3>`) in the subsection and a paragraph made up of multiple `<span>` segments. The goal is to exact the Features section such that the output is an `OrderedDict` of h2/h3 as key and a list of text in the spans as values.

For example, https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/hokusai-the-great-wave-31208, the expected output is:

```
{'Recreate an iconic piece of Japanese art': ['Celebrate your passion for Japanese art when you build this incredible LEGO® version of Hokusai’s The Great Wave.'],
 'Build and relax': ['Art lovers can enjoy a relaxing and immersive building experience as they create this unique artwork from 1,810 pieces.'],
 'Hokusai – The Great Wave': ['Create your own artwork',
  'Build Hokusai’s The Great Wave with layers of LEGO® bricks.',
  'The Great Wave comes to life!',
  'The picture’s multiple layers create a stunning 3D effect.',
  'Finishing touch',
  'Add a decorative tile with Hokusai’s signature.'],
 'Immerse yourself in the world of art': ['Listen to the set’s Soundtrack, tailor-made with content to enhance the time you spend building this Japanese wall art.'],
 'A fantastic gift for art lovers': ['Designed for adults, this stunning piece of 3D art can be proudly displayed on a wall following a rewarding build experience.']}
```

I've tried chaining a couple of if-else and try-excepts to cover edge cases when parsing the HTML structure using `BeautifulSoup`. Though the code works, it looks a little messy and any suggestions/improvements would be very helpful!

```
import re
from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict
from itertools import chain

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def slurp_features(bsoup):
    features = defaultdict(list)

    for div in bsoup.find("div", attrs={"data-test":"pdp-features-accordion-content-child"}).find_all('div'):
        if 'data-test' in div.attrs:
            if div.text:
                if len(div.find_all('h2')) == 1 or len(div.find_all('h3')) == 1:
                    try:
                        header, *texts = div.find_all('span')
                    except ValueError:
                        continue
                    section_text = []                
                    for tt in OrderedDict.fromkeys([t for t in texts]):
                        if isinstance(tt, tuple):
                            section_text += [ttt.text for tttt in chain(*tt)]
                        else:
                            section_text.append(tt.text)
                    features[header.text] += section_text
            else:
                pass
                #print(div)

    features = {k:list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(v)) for k,v in features.items()}
    to_delete = []
    for k,v in features.items():
        for vv in v:
            if vv in features:
                to_delete.append(vv)
                
    for d in to_delete:
        if d in features:
            del features[d]
    return features

response = requests.get("https://www.lego.com/en-us/product/hokusai-the-great-wave-31208")

bsoup = BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('utf8'))
slurp_features(bsoup)
```

Here's some parts of the code that I think can be improved but not sure how to go about it,

- The chain if clauses looks like unnecessary complication `if 'data-test' in div.attrs:` -> `if div.text:` -> `if len(div.find_all('h2')) == 1 or len(div.find_all('h3')) == 1:`
- A for-loop to cast a list into an OrderedDict,  `for tt in OrderedDict.fromkeys([t for t in texts]):`
- This kinda check to see if the text is a tuple, if so flattening the nested list. Otherwise add the text to the `section_text`
- The last part where we loop through the data twice, once to determine what should be removed and then another to actually remove them from the output `features`

Comment: OrderedDict is necessary for ancient python3 versions, but `dict` suffices with cPython interpreters [since 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects).  A validator [outline](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lego.com%2Fen-us%2Fproduct%2Fhokusai-the-great-wave-31208&showoutline=yes) (scroll to bottom) suggests that simplying asking BS4 for H2's plus descendant `.text` would get you a long way toward your scraping goal. Write a (`yield`) generator for that raw datastream, then a consumer which cleans it to your liking.